# Like 'String*' in CAML

Tags: caml-query, caml

How can I write LIKE 'String*' in CAML? I must create a query to display the folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

This gets all folders and files under a specified folder:

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
                <Value Type='Text'>MyFolderPath</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Comment: But i want to see all the files under the root folders and all folders unbder a root folder and when I click I want to see all folders and a all files too.

Comment: Does my edit address your needs?

Comment: No because when I Click folder it no show whot is on folder. It Show nothing,

Comment: I want combine this View with root folder and show all files on folder. Please help me.

Comment: I must have this, and when I click on folder it show me all files and folders on clicked folder.

Comment: And when I use Contains or Beins oit show Me all folders and all files in folder

Comment: Is this a custom web part you are using?  I need more info about what is going on.  You say you need it to do something when you click on the folder.  What code is being executed when you click the folder?

Comment: I use Only Designer 2013 and write Caml Query on it Like your Query i put them to the Designer at View on Document Library

Comment: Onlywhere is <Query/> on Sharepoint Designer I replace it by Your Query, and next i Add <View Scope='RecursiveAll'> but it show me god un til I click another folder. That like work <Eq></Eq>

Comment: You're going to need a customized solution to meet your requirements.

Comment: But why Customized. I only wont to have like Windows Explorator and all structure of folder works. When i Click it show me all files and folders on folder wchich I click. But I only click Specyfic root folder. When I click next folder it shold show me all elements on this folder.

Comment: Window Explorator don't show only first View on folder until it click, or not show all folders in tree and next don't show all files on folder. In Explorator Windows I have got same files, and folders and when I Click Folder it show me next files and folder on this folder.

Comment: When i try this solution in my OneDrive for Business account i get the error `The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.`. How to solve this?

Comment: @Martin, the list view threshold is the limit that database operations (such as queries) can process at one time.  There's not much you can do with this in O365, but you'll see some workarounds if you do a quick google search.  There should even be some answers here on SE, or you can try posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeginsWith in the CAML query.

```
"<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>TestTitle</Value></BeginsWith></Where>";
```

Refer [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms476051(v=office.15).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Like the ViewAttributes = "Scope='All'" in this article: http://www.codegrimoire.com/2013/08/scopes-in-caml-query.html but only Scope='ALL' dont work